# Incrementar una fecha mes a mes PHP

Tags: php, date

Tengo las siguientes variables

```
$fehchaI ='2016-01-01'; 
$fehchaF ='2017-01-31';
```

lo que quiero hacer es que se incrementen mes a mes las fechas y el resultado sea

```
2016-01-01
2016-01-31
2016-02-01
2016-02-28
2016-03-01
2016-03-31
```

o bien

```
    2016-01-01
    2016-02-01
    2016-03-01
    2016-04-01
```

y así hasta llegar a la ultima que es '2017-01-31'

o alguna funcion como la de MySQL :

```
SELECT DATE_ADD("2016-01-01", INTERVAL  1 MONTH);
```

pero para php

Alguien que me pueda ayuda a hacerlo en PHP

Answer (score 2):

Para mostrar el último día del mes:

```
$dt = new DateTime( '2017-02-01' ); 
echo $dt->format( 't-m-Y' );
// Resultado: 28-02-2017
```

Para mostrar el primer día del mes siguiente:

```
$dt = new DateTime( '2017-01-15' );
$dt->modify( 'first day of next month' );
echo $dt->format( 'd-m-Y' );
// Resultado: 01-02-2017
```

Para mostrar el siguiente mes respecto a la fecha dada:

```
$dt = new DateTime( '2017-01-15' );
$dt->modify( 'next month' );
echo $dt->format( 'd-m-Y' );
// Resultado: 15-02-2017
```

<kbd>[Ver los ejemplos online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/728a342b4a37ee6884507526e4af2eedd0f4190f)</kbd>

- [+ Info sobre los formatos relativos](http://php.net/manual/es/datetime.formats.relative.php)
- [+ Info sobre DateTime::modify](http://php.net/manual/es/datetime.modify.php)

Answer (score 0):

Yo usaría `date_add` en conjunto con `date_interval_create_from_date_string` ya que es muy parecida a `DATE_ADD` de MySQL:

```
$fecha = date_create('2016-01-01');
date_add($fecha, date_interval_create_from_date_string('1 month'));
echo $fecha->format('Y-m-d');
// Resultado: 2016-02-01
```

Eso si es por procedimientos, aunque también se puede usar OOP:

```
$fecha = new DateTime('2016-01-01');
$fecha->add(new DateInterval('P1M'));
echo $fecha->format('Y-m-d') . "\n";
```

Espero te sirva. Saludos.